# Overriding Vuetify variables

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify in my project, and I want to use a variable file to override the styles generated by Vuetify.

I'm loading the components and their corresponding styles using the **a-la-carte** method, so I'm NOT importing the Vuetify SASS file using this:

```css
 @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass' 
// Not using this method because I don't want to generate styles that are not being used by
// vuetify components I'm not using
```

Also, my project is using `*.scss`, not `*.sass`.

I'm also injecting a global SCSS file containing mixins and other variables in my `vue.config.js`:

```js
css: {
  sourceMap: productionSourceMap,
  loaderOptions: {
    scss: {
      prependData: `@import '@/scss/_common.scss';`
    }
  }
},
```

I included a Vuetify variable, `$border-radius-root`, in that `common.scss` file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any idea how to do what I want without having to write entirely new CSS rules to override Vuetify's generated stylesheet? Basically I want to change the units that Vuetify uses using their own stylesheet generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the solution is, and I'm dumb for not thinking of this before, to add another loader to `vue.config.js`:

```
css: {
  sourceMap: productionSourceMap,
  loaderOptions: {
    scss: {
      prependData: `@import '@/scss/_common.scss';`
    },
    sass: {
      prependData: `@import '@/sass/_vuetify-variables.sass';`
    }
  }
},
```

Since vuetify is using sass as the css pre-processor, it needs sass-loader to handle the variable overrides and apply it to the framework.

Comment: Tip: you should use correct properties depending on sass version as described is docs:  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#webpack-install

Answer (score 4):

### If you are using Nuxt:

you can add `customVariable` path in your `nuxt.config.js` file, in `vuetify` object

**Note** you have to enable `treeShake`. This option is required for custom SASS variables to work

example:

```js
vuetify: {
    // usually file should be in assets folder
    customVariables: ['~/path/to/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true,
}
```

### If you are using Vue CLI:

1. Create a folder with name: `sass`, `scss`, or `styles`
2. Create new file inside this folder and name it: `variables.scss` or `variables.sass`

**vuetify-loader** will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI’s compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults.

Answer (score 1):

From [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install):

> If you have not installed Vuetify, check out the [**quick-start guide**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#vue-cli-3-install). Once installed, create a folder called `sass`, `scss` or `styles` in your src directory with a file named `variables.scss` or `variables.sass`. The **vuetify-loader** will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI's compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults.

So, the `vuetify-loader` automatically loads `@/scss/variables.scss` in a Vue CLI project, so you could set `$border-radius-root` in that file, and it will overrride the framework default.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default path?